# IOS Can I stop the black screen effect of close detection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function that requires distance detection, but I find a confusing problem. Every time something approaches for more than 1 second, it will go black. Can I stop the black screen on the premise of starting distance detection

```
 [UIDevice currentDevice].proximityMonitoringEnabled=YES;[[NSNotificationCenter 
 defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(proximityStateDidChange:) name:UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void)proximityStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{

if ([UIDevice currentDevice].proximityState) {
    NSLog(@"...");
    

} else {
    NSLog(@"...");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through my extensive review, I found that it was impossible to solve the problem